# Partitioning a graph G into at most O(n/k) connected clusters of radius at most k.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every unweighted n-vertex graph G and every integer k>=1, there exists a partition of G into at most O(n/k) connected clusters of radius at most k.
I dont even have a clue on how to strike this problem. Induction on k??

Comment: What if $G$ is not connected?

Comment: The result should hold recursively..for all the connected components of G.

Comment: Is k a fixed constant? In this case O(n/k)=O(n), so every vertex can belong to its own cluster. (This is the best possible if $G$ has no edges.)

Comment: k is not a constant. G(V,E) can be decomposed into clusters in several ways. One way is to decompose it into singleton nodes(here radius is 0 and size of the cluster is 1). Other way is to decompose it into a single cluster (which is the entire graph. Here radius of the cluster is radius of the graph and size of the cluster is 1).